# Trying to understand "==" & "===" operator behavior in certain scenarios

Tags: javascript

```
 console.log([2] == 2) //returns true
 console.log([2,3] == 2) //returns false
 console.log([2] === 2) //returns false
 console.log([2,3] === 2) //returns false
```

Can someone tell me what is happening behind the scenes in the above lines of code,how JavaScript Engine is performing these tasks

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/6918960

Comment: Keeping it simple: ```==``` means equal value, ```===``` means equal value and equal type. That will hopefully help you to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: `==` - equal value, `===` - equal value and equal type.

Comment: Another useful resource: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the useful resource,just one thing how  type coercion is happening if L.H.S is an array and R.H.S is number or string of same value.

Comment: @BeastLesnar doesn't matter which side has which argument, with an array and a number, they would both be converted to the same basic type. An array will be converted to a number in this case. This is loosely, the result of `Number(array)`, so an empty array is `0`, an array with a single element is the value of that element, an array with multiple elements is `NaN`. The conversion is basically `Number(array.toString())` and `toString` in turn is `array.join()` with the default parameter for joining being `","`. In other words the `array` operand is transformed as if `Number(array.join(","))`

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you so much,it cleared my confusions